# Submitting Forms in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to have a form in my chrome extension popup that has its data processed by js when it's submitted. However, without any errors, nothing happens on submission.

manifest.json

```json
"action":{
  "default_popup": "index.html"
},
"background": {
  "service_workers": ["app.js"]
}
```

index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <form id="form">
    <input id="grade" type="text" placeholder="grade">
    <input id="score" type="text" placeholder="score">
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var form = document.getElementById("form")
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){        
        var grade = document.getElementById("grade").value
        var score = document.getElementById("score").value

        alert(grade)

        chrome.storage.sync.set({grade: grade})

        chrome.storage.sync.get(['grade'], function(result) {
          console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
        });
    })
})
```

Is this happening because I don't include the `<script src="app.js">` tag? Chrome gives an error if any script tags are inside the html of the popup.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var form = document.getElementById("form");

  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var grade = document.getElementById("grade").value;
    var score = document.getElementById("score").value;

    console.log(grade);

    // chrome.storage.sync.set({grade: grade});

    // chrome.storage.sync.get(['grade'], function(result) {
      // console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
    // });
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input id="grade" type="text" placeholder="grade">
  <input id="score" type="text" placeholder="score">
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Comment: Please revise your post to ask a clear, _specific_ question. See [ask].

Comment: I thought preventDefault() just prevents the page from reloading?

Comment: Even after removing it, same thing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251128/discussion-between-walker-and-isherwood).

Comment: There's no server in an extension, the html files are just local files, so `form` won't work. Remove it and just use a normal `button` element to save the inputs.

Comment: Alright, let me try that

Comment: Also remove `background` from manifest.json and add `<script src=app.js></script>` to the end of your html.

Comment: It gives me an error when I add js into my html: 
Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.

Comment: This happens for the onclick="function()"

Comment: Use a separate js file, see [onclick or inline script isn't working in extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13591983)